# Unnesting JSON String stored in a column [BigQuery]

Tags: json, google-bigquery, unnest

I have a table with one of the columns containing a raw JSON string as follows:
[image]

Sample JSON stored in order_lines:

```
{
   "STR_BLK_002":{
      "amount":167,
      "type":"part spare",
      "total_discount":0,
      "color":"Black",
      "is_out_of_stock":false,
      "variable_fields":{
         "Size":"XL",
         "trueColor":"Black"
      },
      "category_id":"44356721",
      "status_list":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "time":"2021-04-01T15:01:54.746Z",
            "status":"ORDER PLACED"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "time":"2021-04-02T10:31:00.397Z",
            "status":"PACKED"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "time":"2021-04-04T10:31:01.719Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "time":"2021-04-04T18:12:06.896Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         }
      ],
      "product_id":270,
      "price_per_quantity":167,
      "quantity":1,
      "maximum_quantity":10,
      "variant_name":"Helmet strap",
      "current_status":30,
      "estimated_delivery":"09 Apr 2021",
      "total_before_discount":167,
      "delivery_statuses":[
         {
            "time":"2021-04-01T15:10:13.594Z",
            "status":"FULFILLABLE"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-02T10:31:00.397Z",
            "status":"PACKED"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-03T10:31:01.197Z",
            "status":"READY_TO_SHIP"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-04T10:31:01.719Z",
            "status":"DISPATCHED"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-04T18:12:06.896Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         }
      ],
      "sku_code":"STR_BLK_002"
   }
}
```

I want to unnest this string so that the key value pairs can be accessed individually. Also the sku_code, ('STR_BLK_002' in the sample shared above) is not available in any other column and the string can contain more a single sku, so if there are 2 sku(s) corresponding to an order then the JSON string would be:

```
{
   "STR_BLK_002":{
      "amount":167,
      "type":"part spare",
      "total_discount":0,
      "color":"Black",
      "is_out_of_stock":false,
      "variable_fields":{
         "Size":"XL",
         "trueColor":"Black"
      },
      "category_id":"44356721",
      "status_list":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "time":"2021-04-01T15:01:54.746Z",
            "status":"ORDER PLACED"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "time":"2021-04-02T10:31:00.397Z",
            "status":"PACKED"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "time":"2021-04-04T10:31:01.719Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "time":"2021-04-04T18:12:06.896Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         }
      ],
      "product_id":270,
      "price_per_quantity":167,
      "quantity":1,
      "maximum_quantity":10,
      "variant_name":"Helmet strap",
      "current_status":3,
      "estimated_delivery":"09 Apr 2021",
      "total_before_discount":167,
      "delivery_statuses":[
         {
            "time":"2021-04-01T15:10:13.594Z",
            "status":"FULFILLABLE"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-02T10:31:00.397Z",
            "status":"PACKED"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-03T10:31:01.197Z",
            "status":"READY_TO_SHIP"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-04T10:31:01.719Z",
            "status":"DISPATCHED"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-04T18:12:06.896Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         }
      ],
      "sku_code":"STR_BLK_002"
   },
   "STR_BLK_008":{
      "amount":590,
      "type":"accessory",
      "total_discount":0,
      "color":"blue",
      "is_out_of_stock":false,
      "variable_fields":{
         "Size":"XL",
         "trueColor":"prussian blue"
      },
      "category_id":"65577970",
      "status_list":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "time":"2021-04-06T15:01:54.746Z",
            "status":"ORDER PLACED"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "time":"2021-04-07T10:31:00.397Z",
            "status":"PACKED"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "time":"2021-04-07T10:31:01.719Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "time":"2021-04-08T18:12:06.896Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         }
      ],
      "product_id":276,
      "price_per_quantity":590,
      "quantity":1,
      "maximum_quantity":5,
      "variant_name":"Car Perfume",
      "current_status":3,
      "estimated_delivery":"09 Apr 2021",
      "total_before_discount":590,
      "delivery_statuses":[
         {
            "time":"2021-04-06T15:10:13.594Z",
            "status":"FULFILLABLE"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-07T10:31:00.397Z",
            "status":"PACKED"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-07T10:31:01.197Z",
            "status":"READY_TO_SHIP"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-08T10:31:01.719Z",
            "status":"DISPATCHED"
         },
         {
            "time":"2021-04-10T18:12:06.896Z",
            "status":"SHIPPED"
         }
      ],
      "sku_code":"STR_BLK_008"
   }
}
```

I want to break this information into separate columns, so that I can fetch the corresponding values for each SKU.

Comment: This link is throwing 404 error. @SergeyGeron

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically what I think you want to do is first transform your column into a array of structs so that instead of having this:

```
{
   "STR_BLK_002": {...},
   "STR_BLK_003": {...}
}
```

You have something like this:

```
[
  {
      "amount":167,
      "type":"part spare",
      "total_discount":0,
       ...
   },
  { 
      "amount":590,
      "type":"accessory",
      "total_discount":0,
      ...
  }
]
```

With the data in that format you can leverage [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) to make each entry into its own row, and then use [JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) to pull out fields into their own columns, for example [JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar)

In order to do this, I built a [Javascript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) that find the keys in the object and then iterates through each key to create an array of structs.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION format_json(str STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
  var obj = JSON.parse(str);
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    arr.push(JSON.stringify(obj[keys[i]]));
  }
  return arr;
""";

SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(formatted_json,'$.amount') as amount
  ,JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(formatted_json,'$.type') as type
  ,JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(formatted_json,'$.total_discount') as total_discount
  ,JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(formatted_json,'$.color') as color
  ,JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(formatted_json,'$.is_out_of_stock') as is_out_of_stock
  ,JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(formatted_json,'$.sku_code') as sku_code
from
testing.json_test
left join unnest(format_json(order_lines)) as formatted_json
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Below should give you good start

```
select  
  json_extract_scalar(line, '$.sku_code') as sku_code,
  json_extract_scalar(line, '$.amount') as amount,
  json_extract_scalar(line, '$.type') as type,
  json_extract_scalar(line, '$.total_discount') as total_discount,
  json_extract_scalar(line, '$.color') as color,
  json_extract_scalar(line, '$.variable_fields.Size') as Size,
  json_extract_scalar(line, '$.variable_fields.trueColor') as trueColor,
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(split(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(order_lines, r'\s', ''), r'"STR_BLK_\d+":{', '"STR_BLK":{'),'"STR_BLK":')) order_line with offset,
unnest([struct('{' || trim(order_line, ',{}}') || '}' as line)]) 
where offset > 0
```

if applied to first example in  your question - output is

[image]

if applied to second example in  your question - output is

[image]

Hope, you can extend this example to whatever final goal you have in mind

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still there's one doubt. The sku_code can be anything and not limited to only 'STR_BLK'. How can I proceed in such cases? @Mikhail